# How to draw a box around a legend in R?

Tags: r, legend

I have a plot with a legend, but I would like to put a box around my legend. How can I code the box around the legend?

```
# My Plot
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(25,40), ylim=c(0,9), type="p")
axis(1)
axis(2)
title(xlab="Temperature (ºC)")
title(ylab="Trial",main="Egg Parasitization Along A Thermal Gradient")

# My Legend       
legend(36,9.3,c("Parasitized","Unparasitized"),cex=1.0,
    bty="n",col=c("blue","red"),pch=c(17,16))
```

Answer (score 6):

These are the default box parameters:

```
 box.lwd = par("lwd"), box.lty = par("lty"),   box.col = par("fg")
```

If you were calling the `legend` function you should already be getting a box, so is it a larger box that you want? Oh, ... I see ... you have `bty="n"` in that legend call so it's *not* printing the box. Just take that out.